# determining the percent of identical responses across multiple variables

Tags: r, database, analysis, data-science

I have a dataset with many variables, including 26 variables all with values ranging from 1-12. I want to remove all rows where at least 80% of the values are identical (more than 21 1's, or more than 21 2's etc.). I'm having trouble thinking of a way to do this in R, and would really appreciate some ideas on how to approach this problem!

when I run the

```
out <- df1[apply(df1, 1, function(x) mean(x == Mode(x)) <= 0.8),]
```

code on the subset of variables in one group, the values of the variables in the other group all become NA.

Here are 60 rows of the dataset with 5 questions from all three conditions included: https://nofile.io/f/gBWymjYmQ2O/dataset

My expected output is df1 (which has 100+ variables) with the rows with greater than 80% identical responses to the 26 variables of interest removed.

Comment: I understand your description.  What I wanted to know is that in the example data you showed, how many rows will be output as I get 48 rows after the removal of NA rows and greater than 80% identical response

Comment: I actually don't want the rows with all NA's to be removed. Just the rows with more than 90% identical values, besides NA's. Does that help?

Comment: In that case `df1[ apply(df1, 1, function(x)  mean(x == Mode(x), na.rm = TRUE) <= 0.8 | all(is.na(x))),]`

Comment: Yesssss that's it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop through the rows of dataset, get the frequency of values, check if the highest frequent value is not more than 80% to create a logical `vector` and remove the rows based on that

```
Mode <- function(x) {
   ux <- unique(x)
   ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
} 

out <- df1[apply(df1, 1, function(x)  mean(x == Mode(x)) <= 0.8),]
```

#### Update

Based on the OP's dataset, there are NAs in the rows and some rows have all NAs.  We can change the code to remove those rows having all NAs and those have 80% same values

```
Mode <- function(x) {
 ux <- unique(x[!is.na(x)])
 ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
 } 

df1[ apply(df1, 1, function(x)  mean(x == Mode(x), na.rm = TRUE) <= 0.8 & !all(is.na(x))),]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:12, 26 *20, replace = TRUE), ncol = 26))
df1[c(1, 3, 7),1:21] <- 5
```

Comment: I'm having some trouble getting this to work right, because these columns are part of a larger dataset with many more variables. I can do this by subsetting the variables of interest, adding an id variable and then adjusting for that added variable by decreasing the percentage, and then subsetting the original dataset by the id's that match; but I'm wondering if theres a nicer way.

Comment: @BenjiKaveladze  If you have other columns as well, subset your dataset by `colsneeded <- 1:5;  df1[apply(df1[colsneeded], 1, function(x)  mean(x == Mode(x)) <= 0.8),]`

Comment: This solution didn't seem to work for me. None of the rows with >.9 similarity were erased when I ran it. When I run just the df1[apply(df1[colsneeded], 1, function(x) mean(x == Mode(x)) <= 0.8),] command, it prints a weird looking data frame where everything is NA

Comment: @BenjiKaveladze  Do you have NAs in the dataset?  If that is the case `mean(x == Mode(x), na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: In the study the dataset came from, participants were put into one of three groups and each group answered different questions. What seems to be happening is when I run the out <- df1[apply(df1, 1, function(x)  mean(x == Mode(x)) <= 0.8),] code on the subset of variables in one group, the values of the variables in the other group all become NA. Do you have any idea of why this could be happening?

Comment: @BenjiKaveladze  You haven't provided a small reproducible example in your post.  So, I was just constructing based on the description.  Please provide your small data using `dput` by editin gin your post and the expected output

Comment: @BenjiKaveladze  There are rows where it is only NAs.  What do you want to do with those rows?  Can we remove those?

Comment: When I use the new method it looks like every row except for the rows of the subset I'm running the function on is just deleted instead of turned into NA.

Comment: are you still using the format df1 <- df1[ apply(df1[1:5], 1, function(x)  mean(x == Mode(x), na.rm = TRUE) <= 0.8 & !all(is.na(x))),] ?

Comment: @BenjiKaveladze  Yes, Can you update your post with the expected output as I am not sure what you are expecting

Comment: @BenjiKaveladze  I get 48 observations after subsetting

Comment: ok, I updated it. Sorry about the lack of clarity, I really appreciate your sticking with me through this.